# Detecting mobile browsers using third party code

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-plus

I would like to detect if visitors to my site are using a mobile browser

My pages already include a lot of third party javascript:

facebook-sdk

google plus button

google analytics code

So instead of writing the javascript to detect mobile myself i imagine that some of all this scripts might already include a function to do this

I haven't found such function so far, i was wondering if anybody could point me to it

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if one of those 3rd party js has mobile-detection. What do you want to know? Screen-size, touch-enabled, phone or tablet, mobile-grade? In many cases Modernizr is sufficient. I suppose google analytics is not interested in form-factor client side. They will detect it server-side.

Comment: In case you don't find suitable code in the existing libraries, you can have a look at [mobile-detect.js](https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js). There you find a list of alternatives as well.